# Wordpress function to award credits depending on form data

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

The intention is to have users fill out a form (CF7) to get Mycred credits. So they give a number in the CF7 form and get it added to their account. Therefore, I put the code below to my functions.php, it will send out the emails from the form but after that, on the page the CF is still loading and doesn't add the credits. Someone know what's wrong here?  Probably I'm missing out some relations somewhere so it gets stuck somewhere in the execution?

```
function addcredits_withform( $contact_form, $submission ){

    $requesting_userid = $submission->get_posted_data( 'submitted_userid' );
    $requested_amount = $submission->get_posted_data( 'number-805' );
    
    mycred_add('addcredits_withform', $requesting_userid, $requested_amount, 'user added credits');
}

add_action ('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'addcredits_withform');
```

I also tried changing the action hook to 'wpcf7_before_send_mail' which as expected only results into the form loading and not even sending the mails.